# Angular12 img src binding generates data-src in template

Tags: angular, typescript, one-trust

I'm getting from my backend an image (in blob) which I need to display in an img tag.

**template.html**

```html
<img class="image" [src]="selectedImage.imageStream" />
```

**component.ts**

```js
getDocument(requestPath: string): Observable < any > {
    return this.http.get(`${Config.apiRoot.uri}${requestPath}`, {
      responseType: 'blob'
      as 'json'
    })
  }

  ** ** ** **

  getAndAssignImage() {
    this.getDocument(this.selectedImage.imageSrc).subscribe({
      next: (streamResp) => {

        const imageStreamReader = new FileReader();

        imageStreamReader.addEventListener('load', () => {
          this.selectedImage.imageStream = imageStreamReader.result;
        }, false);

        imageStreamReader.readAsDataURL(streamResp);
      }
    });
  }
```

Somehow, even if I'm binding to `src` property, the generated html has the base64 image in the `data-src` attribute:

```html
<img _ngcontent-btp-c316="" class="image ng-star-inserted" data-src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD...">
```

Somehow the image is not displayed and I guess it's because the base64 is set in the `data-src` attribute instead of the `src` property, which I'm binding.

I've already checked the base64 is valid and copy/pasting it in a plain html file with just the img src display the image.

What's the problem? Why the img tag has my base64 string in the `data-src` attribute instead of `src`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research we found the issue. We are using OneTrust and the auto blocking feature was preventing the image to display.

[The specifics are here](https://community.cookiepro.com/s/article/UUID-71e7d0a8-03d8-e272-e683-72cadded2ecf?language=en_US) and [here](https://my.onetrust.com/articles/en_US/Knowledge/UUID-301b21c8-a73a-05e8-175a-36c9036728dc) but the fix for us was just adding the `data-ot-ignore` and the `optanon-category` class in order to prevent the OneTrust blocker to mess with this image tag. So the image tag in the end looked like this:

```html
<img data-ot-ignore class="image optanon-category" [src]="selectedImage.imageStream" />
```

You can find how to fix videoplayer issues [here](https://my.onetrust.com/articles/en_US/Knowledge/UUID-301b21c8-a73a-05e8-175a-36c9036728dc)